# Custom string class implementation advice?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, ascii

I'm writing my own string class (just for fun), but I have run into a bit of an issue. I'd like my class to be able to handle both ASCII and Unicode strings. If you assign a `const wchar_t*` to my class, the flag for Unicode is set. If you assign a `const char*`, the Unicode flag is **not** set.

Furthermore, if you try to append a Unicode character to an ASCII string, it will either create an entirely new string that is Unicode, or will reallocate its buffer and convert everything to Unicode (not sure which one I'll do).

Anyway, onto my question: I'm wanting something similar to std::string's `c_str` function. Obviously I would have 2 different functions, one returning a `const char*` ASCII string, and one returning a `const wchar_t*` Unicode string.

Let's say my string is ASCII. If I call the `ToAsciiString()` function, it would simply return a pointer to the internal storage of the string, which doesn't and shouldn't be manually freed because the string dtor will automatically do that.

But if I want my ASCII string in Unicode, I could call `ToUnicodeString()`. But that creates a problem: I would need to allocate a new buffer to convert my ASCII string into. If I did that, then the pointer returned would need to be manually `delete[]`'ed, which defeats the simplicity of std::string's `c_str`, for example.

I'm not sure how I can properly do this.

Comment: Unicode is not an encoding (UTF-8/UTF-16/UTF-32 are encoding). Maybe you want the string to include an encoding state and any new characters must include their encoding state and they are translated as part of the insertion/appending etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to maintain 2 buffers inside your class. In some cases you will have just one, but if both representations are required, you will have to allocate both.

This approach will make using of your class simple. In our days we have gigabytes of RAM. This means that this approach does not sound as something ridiculous unless you need to handle huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like my class to be able to handle both ASCII and Unicode strings.

This is approaching the problem all wrong. If you want a string to contain ASCII or possibly Unicode characters, the solution is simple: store UTF-8.

By definition, a UTF-8 string is ASCII if it doesn't contain any post-ASCII characters. So your string is ASCII unless someone adds a codepoint greater than 127. There's no need to switch back and forth; you handle them both with the same array of bytes.

Also, you seem to be under the common Windowsian notion that `wchar_t*` means "Unicode" and `char*` means "ASCII". They're not. Unicode is a standard that describes what 21-bit codepoints mean and how they relate. The 21-bit codepoints can be stored in a variety of encodings. Your "Unicode" probably means "UTF-16".